# How to map a value in a chloropleth including year slider?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a map based on a concrete variable. However, R keeps giving me the warning 'Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x' although the variable which is in the place of x is included in my dataset. How can I fix this?

I have retrieved the function I am using here from another script in which it works perfectly, therefore I don't know what goes wrong.

```
#the code I am using
Oil <- read_csv2(file = "C:/Users/Gebruiker/Documents/CrudeOil2.csv")
locationOil_df <- geocode(Oil$`Location,`)
NewOil2 <- cbind(Oil, locationOil_df)
NewOil2_2008 <- as.data.frame(NewOil2_2008)

> NewOil2_2008
    X1  id,                  Name,
216 NA 216, Bandar Abbas Refinery,
217 NA 217,      Esfahan Refinery,
218 NA 218,   Kermansheh Refinery,
219 NA 219,       Abadan Refinery,
220 NA 220,       Shiraz Refinery,
                                       Owner,     Location,       Type,
216                         NIOC(Government), Bandar Abbas, Production,
217 Isfahan Oil Refining Company(Government),      Esfahan, Production,
218                               Government,   Kermanshah, Production,
219                               Government,       Abadan, Production,
220                               Government,      Zarghan, Production,
                        Product, Amount(t), Year      lon      lat
216 Crude.Petroleum.Natural.Gas,  209800000 2008 56.26665 27.18322
217 Crude.Petroleum.Natural.Gas,  209800000 2008 51.66597 32.65390
218 Crude.Petroleum.Natural.Gas,  209800000 2008 47.07777 34.32769
219 Crude.Petroleum.Natural.Gas,  209800000 2008 48.29340 30.34730
220 Crude.Petroleum.Natural.Gas,  209800000 2008 52.71349 29.76416

Iran <- getData('GADM', country = 'IRN', level=1)
Iran <- fortify(Iran, region = "NAME_1")



h <- ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data=NewOil2_2008, aes(NewOil2_2008$`Location,`, fill = NewOil2_2008$`Amount(t),`), map=Iran) + 
  ylim(c(20,41)) + xlim(c(44,65)) + theme_void() +
  labs(fill = "Number of events")
```

I expect a chloropleth of Iran with the five provinces present in my dataset highlighted with a scale for the variable NewOil2_2008$`Amount(t),`. However, now I get the error warning 'Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x'. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [example]

Comment: Thank you, I hope my edit will provide more information.